# Is HTTP 301 the best way to integrate an existing website with AWS CloudFront?

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

We have an existing web product that uses a lot of static images, css files, js libs and other static content. Whenever a page is loaded, browser usually has to make dozens of additional HTTP requests to retrieve all that content which almost doubles load time. We wanted to put the content to Amazon's CloudFront to improve the load times and I am trying to choose between the two possible ways of implementing this.

1). Going through every single reference to such content and replacing it with a request to CloudFront. E.g. images/image.jpg would become qwerty.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg. This will result in a "true" integration but it would be practically impossible for me to implement this. Especially for different JS libs which come with their own images that they choose dynamically.

2). Leave images/image.jpg as it is and tell server to do 301 to CloudFront for such requests. The problem with this implementation is that the requests will actually have to be routed all the way to the server before server can redirect them to CloudFront.

So basically I am not sure if 301 is a good idea. This will work only if the time to route request to our server is negligible compared to the time it takes server to send this image back to the client. Additionally I don't know how easily server will handle load spikes - will it survive if a traffic spike happens and it will have to serve a lot of 301 redirects (although I assume it will, since doing this should be much easier than retrieving the files from file system and outputting them). Please let me know if you have any experience with this or thoughts on the matter (including other potential ways of implementing this integration).

Comment: You probably want to go with 1 with a cloudfront distribution using a custom origin (your site). CSS/Javascript will work automatically provided they are using paths without a domain name.

Comment: Well, origin shouldn't be a problem since we are hosting with Amazon already (EC2). Referencing content seems to me problematic though. Unless I am misunderstanding something, according to Amazon's articles CloudFront is used only when you reference it explicitly as qwerty.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg

Comment: That is correct, however, css files for example will reference an image relative to itself. If the css file requests an image /path/to/image.jpg and you request the css via cloudfront. The browser will also make the image request via cloudfront.

Comment: Oh, I see! Yeah, that would actually help a bit but many other paths, e.g. images referenced in dynamically generated HTML, will still point to the original server. I'll try to run a few tests and will check how much of a different a 301 redirect will make.